# How to mass import database files into mySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have roughly 52,000KB of raw database files (folders containing .MYI, .MYD, .frm, .opt, etc.) I have been asked now to move all of these files into our mySQL database.

Currently, said database is empty and I simply need to export these files from my PC to the database.

Thank you in advance for any help and understanding my what will probably be simple question!

Note: We have phpmyadmin already setup and I will be happy to give other information if necessary.

Comment: 52,000KB is just 52MB. That's almost zero data unless you mean something else.

Comment: Ideally you have a SQL dump. Second best is a backup of the MySQL server data, but you may have trouble getting that to boot unless you can match the MySQL version you use to access that with the version used to create it in the first place. If this was a MySQL 5.5 system, for example, use the latest 5.5 version to access it. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: @tadman I guess phrasing it as 52MB might have been a bit better. Never the less that small amount of data is hours upon hours of work lol

Comment: Sometimes tiny files contain a lot of important data, it's true. This recovery process is complicated because you've lost the original server, presumably. `mysqldump` can produce portable dumps, these are the ideal. For an in-place recovery you're going to have to experiment. Back that data up in several places before you try anything.

Comment: @tadman Thank you man. May seem like a tenuous problem but you've made my night much more simple

Answer (score 0):

you can do it a lot faster via command line:

```
$ mysql -uuser -p
$ use `desired-db`
$ source /path/to/dump.sql
```

this will import the file of any size, only catch is you'd do this per database and not all at once.